# Search for a file using the Windows Run Dialog Box

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, search, windows-search, run-dialog

I am attempting to automate a Windows Search for a file name. My method work on several folders; however, it fails on a folder named "part #". My process was to

1. Search for a file within the part # folder using Windows Explorer.
2. Copy the search path:

> search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results%20in%20part%20#&crumb=System.Generic.String%3A12345&crumb=location:C%3A%5CUsers%5CUsername%5CDocuments%5Cpart%20#

3. Now I can change the part # from 12345 and launch this path from the run dialog box.

Unfortunately, for folders with a hashtag in the name, the run dialog box does not open the search; it only refreshes itself. Is there a way around this behavior such as escaping the character somehow? When directly pasted into the Explorer address bar, the path works as expected.

Limitations: The part # folder is on a network drive (but I get the same behavior if it is in my documents folder) so I cannot rename it without breaking shortcuts for other users and I would like to use the search process that I outlined above rather than using another method to perform the search.

Comment: When the above path is pasted into the Run Dialog Box, I would like it to open the search as it would for a folder without a '#' sign.